# Bindable Picker's Title not working

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a Xamarin project and I need to use a picker, so Xamarin's native picker do not have ItemsSource. I've found an implementation that works almost fine, here is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AnyNameSpace.Mobile.CustomControls
{
   public class BindablePicker : Picker
   {
       public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
             BindableProperty.Create( 
                                    "ItemSource",
                                    typeof (IEnumerable),
                                    typeof (BindablePicker), 
                                    default(IEnumerable), 
                                    BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                    propertyChanged: OnItemsSourceChanged);

        public static BindableProperty SelectedItemBindableProperty =
              BindableProperty.Create(
                                    "SelectedItemBindable",
                                    typeof (object),
                                    typeof (BindablePicker),
                                    default(object),
                                    BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                    propertyChanged: OnSelectedItemChanged);

        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable) GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public object SelectedItemBindable
        {
            get { return GetValue(SelectedItemBindableProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItemBindableProperty, value); }
        }

        public BindablePicker()
        {
            SelectedIndexChanged += OnSelectedIndexChanged;
            base.Title = "Seleccione"; // Here I want a custom title, but this is ignoring me :(
        }

        private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
        {
            var picker = bindable as BindablePicker;
            if (picker?.Items == null) return;
            picker.Items.Clear();
            if (newvalue == null) return;
            foreach (var item in ((IEnumerable)newvalue).Cast<object>().Where(item => item != null))
                picker.Items.Add(item.ToString());
        }

        private void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (Items != null && (SelectedIndex < 0 || SelectedIndex > Items.Count - 1))
                SelectedItemBindable = null;
            else if (Items != null) SelectedItemBindable = Items[SelectedIndex];
        }

        private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
        {
            var picker = bindable as BindablePicker;
            if (newvalue == null) return;
            if (picker?.Items != null) picker.SelectedIndex = picker.Items.IndexOf(newvalue.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem is: When a set the Title property on XAML or even in C# It always says in Title property "Choose an item" I've tried to set Picker's Title in constructor but do not work.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the Title-Property through Xaml or Code works fine. 
I just tested this in a small project.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:control="clr-namespace:AnyNameSpace.Mobile.CustomControls" 
         x:Class="TestApp.BindablePickerTestPage">

  <control:BindablePicker Title="MyTitle"></control:BindablePicker>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: thank you very much guys, the problem was that: My app's background was white !!! so I never see picker's title

Answer (score 1):

It may simply be a case that the value is getting overwritten somewhere further down the controls lifecycle.

Perhaps try and subscribe to the `OnAppearing` event and set the title there

Comment: thank you very much guys, the problem was that: My app's background was white !!! so I never see picker's title